# I want to make a video view inside a UIView with rounded rectangles

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, uiview

I want to make a video view inside a UIView.

I want to make a video view that is displayed similarly to when you first start the Paper by [FiftyThree App](https://www.fiftythree.com/paper).

So I tried to make a simple video view [Xcode project](https://github.com/kawai-hiroyuki/KHFVideoViewBeta).

But it's view didn't become rounded rectangle.
Do you know how to make a video view like the Paper App?

Comment: I fixed my Xcode project. It is my final answer. If you got same problem, please check it. [My Project](https://github.com/kawai-hiroyuki/KHFVideoViewBeta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like this;

[image]

Just do this:

1. Add QuartzCore framework
2. Change your `viewDidLoad`.

This:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    KHFVideo *video = [KHFVideo videoNamed:@"sample.mp4"];
    KHFVideoView *videoView = [[KHFVideoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    videoView.layer.cornerRadius = 150.f;
    videoView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [videoView setVideo:video];
    videoView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];

    [videoView play];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: It a good solution! but I got a new question. I will mind Video size and View size are different.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand.

Comment: Don’t worry about it. You are good adviser.

Comment: Ok! I accepted it. Thank you, Rashad!